# How to stop propagating ajaxerror event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have client side logger which POST any client side error to server for logging.

```
var logger = (function ($) {
     var module = {};
    module.log = function (obj) {
        try {           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                url: '/jslog'
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
                // how to stop progating ajaxError here?
            })
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
            // how to stop progating ajaxError here?
        }
    }
    return module;

})(jQuery);
```

then on the page i have attached two event handlers.

1. to handle any ajax error
2. to handle any java script error

   ```
   $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
           logger.log({ jqxhr: jqxhr })
       });

    window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
       logger.log({ message: msg, url: url, line: line })
    }
   ```

**ISSUE**

The logger.log internally use ajax POST to send log to the server. So if the logging itself fails, it fires `$(document).ajaxError` again, which again tries to log error and fails and so on. It goes in continuous loop.

Is there any way to STOP propogating `ajaxError` in `catch` or `fail` event handler?

If not, then how to POST without using AJAX?

or is there any other better way to handle this (without using anyother 3rd party lib)

Answer (score 0):

Most times when I need to break an endless loop I throw in a:

`return;`

As far as posting AJAX, you can use this kind of solution which has a noCache helper to avoid dreadful IE ajax caching. jQuery tends to handle ajax cache itself, so a noCache option is almost a necessity in my opinion.

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
        function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
    ).join('&');

    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    noCacheRequest('POST',url,xhr);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { 
        success(xhr.responseText); }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}

function noCacheRequest(http_method,url,request_object) {
    var no_cache = '?' + new Date().getTime();
    return request_object.open(http_method.toUpperCase(), url + no_cache, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the url in `ajaxError()` and don't make log request if error is from the logging url:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
  if ( settings.url !== '/jslog' ) {
    logger.log({ jqxhr: jqxhr });
  }
});
```